# Sale este error al momento de compilar la app

Tags: flutter, dart

Al momento de compilar la **app** me sale este error, no se porque se está produciendo alguien me podría ayudar?

Anexo el en texto el **error**:

> Compiler message:
>       /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_widgets-0.1.5/lib/src/visibility_detector/src/visibility_detector_layer.dart:277:18:
>   Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
>           return super.addToScene(builder, layerOffset);
>                        ^
>       Compiler failed on C:\Users\brayan\Desktop\FluxStore-woo 1.4.1\source\lib\main.dart
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 765
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm64'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
>   BUILD FAILED in 5m 2s
>     Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Seria de mucha ayuda que compartas el mensaje de error directamente, en lugar de una imagen, ya que no  se logra ver exactamente que dice el mensaje.

Comment: Hola. Ver el contenido de esta imagen desde un móvil es casi que imposible. Desde la versión web normal es ya de por sí difícil. Para que puedan ayudarte de forma rapida y efectiva, procura por favor incluir tus trazas de error como texto y no como imagen. Igual con todo lo que quieras mostrar en tus preguntas.